# Translation of a complex complement

Tags: traduction, conjonctions, compléments

I am translating an official letter and I am struggling with this sentence (part of a numbered item list)

> Receipt from you of a Contract the terms of which we are satisfied with

I was able to modify it a bit for clarity, into:

> La réception de votre proposition du Contrat, dont les termes sont pour nous satisfaisants

I expecially wanted to avoid *Avec les termes duquel*. However, I realized I had to make changes to both parts of the sentence and I am afraid it changes the meaning too much.

**What is a better translation for this sentence?**

Comment: "d'une votre" is incorrect.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps edited. It was from a previous draft, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how your list of items is introduced, the article might be optional; no capital for *contrat* and there should be no comma before *dont*. I would slightly modify the first part of your sentence that way:

> Réception de votre part d'un contrat dont les termes sont pour nous satisfaisants

or, to remove the potential ambiguity introduced by *de votre part*:

> Réception d'un contrat de votre part dont les termes sont pour nous satisfaisants

Comment: "Réception de votre part" me laisse penser que ce sont les autres qui ont reçu le contrat.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps ok, réponse modifiée.

Comment: About the article, in depends on how the list is introduced.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Indeed, answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

Je tenterai un :
Réception de votre contrat dont les termes nous sont satisfaisants.